# Broil meringue cookies?

Tags: meringue, broiling

I wanted to make these meringue cookies. The instructions say to bake them for 90 mins at 100, but our oven only broils and we're still waiting to have it fixed. If possible, how long and what temperature would I bake the meringue cookies at? Ty! :)

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SA! Have a look at the [Tour](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/tour) and [Help Center](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/help) when you get a chance.

Answer (score 4):

I would just heat the oven with broil. Then switch if off, wait until  temperature drop to around 110-120C and put meringue in. Then just wait until oven cool off.
Tat way the inside would be chewy, if you want more chrunch burn it with torch before putting in oven.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the broiler, the result will be nothing like what the original recipe intended. Meringue cookies get to be what they are by being baked very low and slow - you can think of it as more of a dehydrating process than a baking process.

Have you ever had a pie with broiled meringue topping? That's what you'll get if you put your meringue mass under the broiler. You can decide that this is what you want, make it and eat it, but nobody would recognize it as a "cookie". It is also advisable to put it in some kind of vessel, because else you'll get a mess.

If you do it that way, you put the oven on broiler (the temperature doesn't matter - I haven't ever seen ovens which let you choose it while on broiler setting) and let it run until you have gotten a crust with gold colored edges.